# c# textbox and mysql table interaction

Tags: c#, mysql, select, textbox

I have developed a software with Visual Studio 2015-2017 and briefly speaking I have a textbox that send it's content as a parameter to a command on a MySql database to return the value in a DataGridView. It's a software to organize every 
environmental complaint sent from a webpage.

My question is: Can I use that ONE textbox to search content for any row in a database table?

Like using the textbox to return every single environmental complaint with a persons name and using the same one to return every single environmental complaint with the complaint location.

It would be something like:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE anything on a table = textbox parameter;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, not in any normal sense the way you have shown, however you can build up a query to include the columns you want to search. I mean how are you (or sql) going to deal with non text fields and all sorts of other shenanigans

Example of what might get your started

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE 'val' IN (field1, field2, field3, field4, ...)
```

or

```
WHERE field1 LIKE '%val%' or field2 LIKE '%val%' etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like separate the data in the same textbox. Then you could probably separate with spaces or lines using "\n" for new line or  " " * x where x is an integer for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as an ideia and it aparrently works :

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = 'Person name' or complaintType = 'Person name'...

and so on with all the fields that i want, and "Person name" being the textbox parameter sent to the command...

thanks for the help!